# How to target my randomly created ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

I have pasted all of my code to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Adnaves/hLGsH/)

What my system should be able to do is create a house with a random ID and set a max capacity of inhabitants in the house. You can then create some people and and drag them on to the house. When 2 people are dragged on top of a house, the house will show a bounce effect and a baby will appear.

My problem right now is that I can't seem to figure out how to target the random ID of my house. So right now if you create more than one house, but only move two people into one of them, all of the houses will "bounce" since I'm targeting the .House class:

```
if(this.aPeople.length == 2)
    {
        // TODO: Create a new Person
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.House').effect('bounce');
        }, 0, function(){

        } ); 
(From line 212)
```

Try to create a house in the results of [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Adnaves/hLGsH/) and click on it. Here you'll get the option to delete the house. The way I targeted my click function there was like this:

```
var iDivHouseId = $(this).attr('id');
$('#WindowDisplayHouseInfo').data('current-elem-id', iDivHouseId);
(on line 33 and 34)
```

At some point I would also like the if(this.aPeople.length == 2) to include that it has to be male and female to make a baby.

The gender I just get by:

```
var sPersonGender = $("#gender input[type='radio']:checked").val();
```

I really hope that you can help me out with some of it or at least point me in the right direction. I'm getting a bit frustrated by looking at the same code with no progress for to long. Feel free to play around with the JSFIDDLE..

Comment: $('#' + iRandomId) instead of $('.House') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice not to use id for this. Check http://jsfiddle.net/hLGsH/10/.
Create a new house like this:

```
var objHouse = $('<div id="' + iRandomId + '" class="House" title="' + sStreetName + '" />');
objHouse.appendTo('.HouseContainer');
```

Then store DOM object in class instance:

```
oHouse.setObj(objHouse);
...
function House()
{
  var obj;
  this.setObj = function(o) {
    obj = o;
  }
...
```

and use `obj.effect('bounce');` to bounce only this object.

Answer (score 0):

either use a `array` to hold all the `id`s, and reference them by index, or just dont use a random one (use #1, #2) and create a `.data("id", math.floor(math.random) * 999999999)` and use that for the user to see a "id".

or you could get it with your event handler `$(".house").handler(function(){ babyIn = $(this).attr("id")})` or something to that tone. if you do this make sure to use a global variable.

also

> the house will show a bounce effect and a baby will appear

rofl.

Answer (score 0):

there seem to be other bugs and for some reason the house the person was dragged into doesn't seem to be the one it was actually dragged into. but to answer your question and atleast give you an idea what to do, you can ad a variable in the House class `var self = this;` and then the queries will be `$("#"+self.getId())...`

[here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/hLGsH/7/)
note lines 194, 219, 212

**EDIT**
also, I see that in `$('#BtnCreateHouse').click(function()...` you attach events to `".House"` when you use `oHouse`, you should attach a house-specific event to the house, not to all houses. again, the solution is using `"#"+oHouse.getId()` or `"#"+iRandomId`

[here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/hLGsH/13/)
note lines 29,31,51